How do I stay sane when not only do I have too much idle time at work and unwanted drop-by visits from fellow workers?
I am not busy enough at work , I have talked to boss and take on work whenever he can find it but still a lot of slow days - that’s bad enough.  But I work in an open foyer area so employees are constantly passing back and forth and one will stop and drone on for almost an hour at times.  Another just plops in a chair and scrolls through his phone 5 or 6 times a day.  I welcome occasional conversation but I have no privacy and I still try to look busy as I obviously can’t say “Excuse me, I’m busy” cuz I’m obviously not. I feel an internal scream all the time and I don’t dislike the people but the monotonous daily stuff is killing me.  Plus I’m just a few years from retirement so finding another job isn’t a viable solution.  How do I stay sane?

Put on a big headphone. When someone tries to talk to you, point your fingers to the headphone and signal that you are talking to someone via that headphone.

Go find some corporate mischief to get up to
There are any N number of problems at your company right now that are in everyone's too hard basket.
Rather than wait for your boss to give you work, find something that irritates you at work, that you could fix - and go fix it.
As the old adage goes - it is easier to ask for forgiveness than permission.

Automate your own job.

When I don't have enough to do, that opens me up to learning new things.
No matter what your age, it is possible to learn new things that would help you in your current job (or in your retirement). There are umpteen videos and virtual courses on the web to help you learn nearly anything. The hard part is to find a subject that you think you can justify spending company time learning. Once you get started, the hard part is limiting the focus as there is so much stuff out there.
What types of things could be valuable to a company to learn? Lots of stuff from new accounting regulations to human resource concepts to sales and marketing techniques to production management to computer security to ... You get the idea. Even if something doesn't directly connect to your job as it is today, studying it can help you be a better person and better employee.
You have a few years to retirement. Use those years wisely.
Use headphones and have a notebook open to take notes in. When someone wants to talk, point to those and say that you are studying at this moment.
